# Inserting a box with shaded background text, in plain TeX.

Tags: color, plain-tex, shading

I'm using Plain TeX and trying to create a box that has a shaded background, containing a mixture of both mathmode and textmode TeX.   It would be great if I could add colour to the background (i.e. like black text over a pale yellow background) but grayscale would be fine, as well.

I've looked around and I've found some implementations of this but I have not found a flexible Plain TeX package.  Is there not one?  Perhaps I don't know what to search for.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at OPmac, petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html

Comment: Apologies, it appears I did not try OPmac.   I've installed csplain and have tried setting text colors using both \coltext and \localcolor, and the \coloron macro.  {\localcolor\Red blah} prints out black on white text.  \coloron\Yellow\Blue{blah2} prints out a black box.  \coltext\Yellow\Blue{blah blah blah} complains about an undefined control sequence.

Comment: I notice the colors do not appear in the dvi file, and if I use either dvips or dvipdf, neither add in the colours.  I suspect there's some kind of set-up problem with these macros but the documentation doesn't seem to indicate you need anything other than csplain... Aha!  I seem to have figured it out.  You don't run csplain, you run pdfcsplain.   It appears if you output to dvi first, it strips-out the colours.

Comment: You can use TikZ with Plain TeX. Try using pdfTeX to compile your doc to produce pdf output directly, I don't think there is any advantage to output DVI, except for synchronisation in some setups.

Comment: I am unable to get the \setbgcolor macro in OPmac to work.  Strange since all the other color macros seem to be working.

Comment: It seems TikZ is the library that does what I want.  Took a little while to find some good documentation: http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf

Comment: \setrgbcolor from opmac trick 0021 works at my computer. I don't know where is your problem. Give example. You can use `pdftex` instead `pdfcsplain`. Last: \setrgbcolor does colored background to the full page but your question differs: you need a color as background only of a selected box.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
\input opmac

\def\yellowbox#1{\setbox0=\vbox{{\medskip#1\medskip}}%
   {\localcolor \Yellow \hrule height\ht0 width\wd0}\kern-\ht0
   \box0
}

\yellowbox{
This is text
$$
  a^2+b^2=c^2 \eqno (1)
$$
another text.
}
\bye
```

If you want to print only coloured rectangles then you need not TikZ. TeX primitives `\vrule` or `\hrule` are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered in comments.  It appears the TikZ library, combined with OPmac does the job.  When I switch to TikZ I have to use pdftex, which disables the epsf macros.  So now I import my images via OPmac.

The only downside to this I see at present is I can't use psfrag with this set-up.  But thankfully my current application does not call for psfrag.